# Simplifying Binomial coefficients within summations

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I have the following equations:
$$q_b^{(n)}=\frac{\sum_\limits{k=2}^n{p_{k,b}^{(n)}kE(T_k^{(n)})}}{\sum_\limits{k=2}^n{kE(T_k^{(n)})}}$$
\
$$p_{k,b}^{(n)}=\frac{{{n-b-1}\choose{k-2}}}{{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}}$$
\
$$\sum_\limits{k=2}^n{{{n-k}\choose{b-1}}}={{n-1}\choose{b}}$$
\
$$E({T_k^{(n)}})=\frac{2}{k(k-1)}$$
\
I want to show that the following is true:
$$q_b^{(n)}=\frac{\frac{1}{b}}{\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{k}}}\propto\frac{1}{b}$$
 \
 Substituting into my original equation, I get
 $$q_b^{(n)}=\frac{\sum_\limits{k=2}^n\frac{{{n-b-1}\choose{k-2}}}{{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}}k\frac{2}{k(k-1)}}{\sum_\limits{k=2}^n{k\frac{2}{k(k-1)}}}$$
 \
 This can be simplified a bit to:
 $$q_b^{(n)}=\frac{2\sum_\limits{k=2}^n\frac{{{n-b-1}\choose{k-2}}}{{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}}\frac{1}{(k-1)}}{2\sum_\limits{k=2}^n{\frac{1}{(k-1)}}}$$
 \
 This can be cleaned up further to read:
 $$q_b^{(n)}=\frac{\sum_\limits{k=2}^n\frac{{{n-b-1}\choose{k-2}}}{{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}}\frac{1}{(k-1)}}{\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{(k)}}}$$
 \
 Now I just need to show that 
$${\sum_\limits{k=2}^n\frac{{{n-b-1}\choose{k-2}}}{{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}}\frac{1}{(k-1)}}=\frac{1}{b}$$
\
Expanding the denominator I get
$${\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{{{n-b-1}\choose{k-2}}}{\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-2)!}}\frac{1}{(k-1)}}$$

This is equal to
$${\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{{{n-b-1}\choose{k-2}}(k-2)!(n-k-2)!}{{(n-1)!}}}$$

Expanding the binomial coefficient gives me
$${\sum_\limits{k=2}^n\frac{(n-b-1)!(k-2)!(n-k-2)!}{{(n-1)!(k-2)!(n-b-k-3)!}}}$$

Cancelling the $(k-2)!$ gives me
$${\sum_\limits{k=2}^n\frac{(n-b-1)!(n-k-2)!}{{(n-1)!(n-b-k-3)!}}}$$

But now I'm not sure where to go from here to get this to look like $1/b$